# CSS 100% width but avoid scrollbar

Tags: css

This is probably a variation on something that has been solved dozens of times but CSS really makes me feel like a fool.

I am trying to build a widget that can be positioned and sized in a variety of ways. It's a pretty simple layout - fixed-height header, fixed-height footer, and a body that takes up the remaining space. The overall width and height varies. The content of the body needs to scroll. I have the overall container, header, footer, and body sizing ok.

But what I want is for the body to scroll when it needs to WITHOUT shrinking content to the left when the scrollbar appears. That is, I want the body to be as wide as it can MINUS the scrollbar that would be there iF it needed to scroll, so that when it DOES need to scroll there is no shrink. In effect, I want this:

```
| - - - unknown width - - -|
+--------------------------+
| content                |*|
| might                  |*|
| scroll                 |*|
+--------------------------+
```

I want the content that might scroll to be as wide as it can MINUS the potential scrollbar width (|*| region).

What I have now is something like this:

```
<div id="content" style="position: absolute; overflow-y: auto; width: 100%">
    <div id="scrollContent" style="???">
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried margins, padding, even %-widths for the inner-most div and all 'do the shift' thing. I also need this to work in FF3, IE7/8 and (fantasy?) IE6.

Comment: Does anyone have any idea how to implement this? Seems like a common problem.

Comment: Look at this. it may be useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028584/browsers-scrollbar-is-under-my-fixed-div/41969534#41969534

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `overflow: scroll` instead of `overflow: auto` - that'll force a scrollbar to always appear.

Comment: Well that certainly prevents the shift/shrink but I was really hoping to not have to do that.

Comment: @n8wrl: That's really the best you can do with CSS alone.

Comment: I have `overflow: scroll;` and `width: 100%;` and the element is still too wide (there is a horizontal scrollbar).

Answer (score 19):

[The answer by Mattias Ottosson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34884924/828584) to another question offers a crucial piece of information - the `vw` units are based on the viewport width *including* the scrollbar, while percentages will be based on the available width which *doesn't* include the space taken up by the scrollbar. In other words, for an element taking up the full width of the page, the width of the scroll bar can represented as `calc(100vw - 100%)`

If we have a top-level element taking up `100%` of the available width, then we can use this to control what changes size when the scrollbar becomes visible. Let's say our goal layout is something like this:

```
.app {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 50vh 1fr;
}
```

Where we want the middle column to be 50% as wide as the viewport height and the rest of the width divided between the left and right column. If we used that, then the addition of a scrollbar means that the horizontal space lost to the scrollbar (about 15px on chrome) is taken out of the width of the left and right columns equally. This can cause an ugly shift when a ui change causes the scrollbar to appear while the main content in the grid remains the same or similar. See the first snippet below.

We can use the calculated width of the scrollbar to instead only shrink the right column:

```
.app {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: calc((100vw - 50vh)/2) 50vh calc(100% - (50vh + 100vw)/2);
}
```

See the second snippet below. Unfortunately this means the `fr` units can't be used and the width of the columns must be specified a little more manually. In this case the width of the left column is half of the viewport width minus the `50vh` taken up by the center column. The width of the right column is the space remaining from the *available width* (`100%` rather than `100vw`) after subtracting the combined width of the left and center columns. This is clearer in the formula:

```
calc(100% - ((100vw - 50vh)/2) - (50vh))
```

which reduces to the one above

**First snippet, ugly jump when scrollbar appears**

```js
$('button').click(() => {
  $('.footer').toggle()
})
```

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  font-family: 'Archivo', sans-serif ;
}
.app {
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 50vh 1fr;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
}
.left-column, .center-column, .right-column {
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 50vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.left-column {
  border-right: none;
  background-color:#def;
}
.center-column {
  background-color:#e1ebbd;
}
.right-column {
  text-align: left;
  border-left: none;
  background: #fb1;
}
.footer {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  height: 2000px;
  background: #753;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="app">
    <div class="left-column">
      Left
    </div>
    <div class="center-column">
      Center
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script><br>
      <button>Toggle footer</button>
    </div>
    <div class="right-column">
      Right
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
 </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**second snippet, right column shrinks when scrollbar appears**

```js
$('button').click(() => {
  $('.footer').toggle()
})
```

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  font-family: 'Archivo', sans-serif ;
}
.app {
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: calc((100vw - 50vh)/2) 50vh calc(100% - (50vh + 100vw)/2);
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
}
.left-column, .center-column, .right-column {
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 50vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.left-column {
  border-right: none;
  background-color:#def;
}
.center-column {
  background-color:#e1ebbd;
}
.right-column {
  text-align: left;
  border-left: none;
  background: #fb1;
}
.footer {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  height: 2000px;
  background: #753;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="app">
    <div class="left-column">
      Left
    </div>
    <div class="center-column">
      Center
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script><br>
      <button>Toggle footer</button>
    </div>
    <div class="right-column">
      Right
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
 </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great explanation! But there is a simpler formula: `grid-template-columns: calc((100vw - 50vh) / 2) 50vh 1fr;`, that is the left column width is half of the viewport width minus the centre column width, and the right column width is the remaining container width (which is the left column width minus the scrollbar width, or equivalently the viewport width minus the left column width minus the centre column width minus the scrollbar width, or equivalently the container width minus the left column width minus the centre column width).

Answer (score 4):

The only way you can "get" and use the scrollbar-width with pure CSS is to actually have the scrollbar *be* there. Now, we don't want to force the scrollbar be *visible* all the time, so what we have to do is this:
Make a container for all of the website's content that always has the scrollbar shown, and hide it. It's surprisingly simple!
I've created [a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/GustvandeWal/4jmhz35b/). Here it is as a snippet:

```css
/* The trick: */

html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
}

body > * {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin-right: -100px;
  padding-right: 100px;
}

/* Other styling: */

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  user-select: none;
  --color: rgb(255 191 191);
}

header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  --color: rgb(191 191 255);
}

body > * > div {
  background-color: var(--color);
  border: 3px solid;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

label::before {
  position: relative;
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  margin: 0 10px;
  top: .2em;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: .1em;
}

input:checked + label::before {
  background-color: var(--color);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #FFF;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

input:not(:checked) ~ div {
  display: none;
}

input ~ div {
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div>I am sticky!</div>
</header>
<main>
  <div>Hello world!</div>
  <input id="foo-2" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="foo-2">Click me</label>
  <div>Let's scroll</div>
</main>
```

The trick is giving the containing elements a negative margin and positive padding to the right. The offset used for these two properties can exceed the scrollbar-width, so making it `100px` is plenty — I can't imagine any browser or website having scrollbars wider than `20px`, let alone `100px`.

---

By the way: The reason I'm applying these styles to every direct child of `body`, instead of having a single `#container` element, is because otherwise `position: sticky` wouldn't work. To have that feature work on an element, it can only have one anscestor with scrolling capabilities.

`html` **contains** `#container` **contains** `sticky element` **-> does not work**

`html` **contains** `sticky container` **-> does work**

Comment: Very nice answer

Comment: Unrelated to this question, in your snippet, why do you replace the checkbox with your own?

Comment: @huyz, thanks! I recreate almost every UI element if it can remain accessible (which it isn't in the snippet, btw). That way, I can 1. animate the elements a little better (`input` elements are void elements and cannot have pseudo elements, for example) and 2. provide a more robust implementation (that being more cross-browser & future-proof by not allowing browser styles to begin with, but creating my own from scratch). See [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/GustvandeWal/chopr7gj/)

Answer (score 2):

Why not displaying always the scrollbars, even when there is no need to scroll?

You can achieve this by setting `overflow:scroll;` to the container.

Answer (score 2):

Add another wrapper inside the element that will have the overflow:auto style and set it to about 18px narrower. The scrollbar should appear in that 18px gap.

Comment: +1, but since the OP doesn't know the width of the container, he would need JavaScript to implement this.

Comment: With FF & IE9 (coming to a browser near you!) do something like (FF) `width: -moz-calc(100% - 16px);`

Comment: @Stephen Except where the scrollbar is 27x (or whatever). Hoorah.

Comment: i used 16px, i'd rather a scrollbar clip a tiny bit than leaving a tiny gap. Also did this by using a wrapper and setting margin-right 16px allowing the original element to stay at 100% with no tomfoolery.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem that is similar that I used the below solution for, I am not sure if this can be a solution to what you want to do, but it could be.

I had a div that resized to content automatically, and then the scroll was added, shrinking the inside, so that the table in it wrapped text, instead of making the container that much wider. The unwanted effect is seen in the below Old example, if the textarea is resized downward and the scroll appears.

My ugly solution was to add a div inside the overflow-y:auto-div, that had display:inline-block, and to add yet another small inline-block div after it, that was 19 pixels wide (reserved for scrollbar) and a pixel high. That little div would appear beside the real div when the browser resized the div to the content, and when the scrollbar appear, the small div is pushed down under the real div, and the real div keeps it's with. It will cause a one pixel bottom "margin", but hopefully not a problem. When no scrollbar ppears, there is 19 pixel of unused space beside the real div, as described in the Question.

(The outermost div is just there to replicate my setup/problem.)

Old:

```
<div style="display:inline-block">
  <div style="max-height:120px; overflow-y:auto; border:1px solid gray">
    <table border=1><tr>
       <td>I do not</td><td>want this to</td>
       <td>add breaks in the text.</td>
    </tr></table>
    <textarea rows=3 cols=15>Resize me down</textarea>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
```

New:

```
<div style="display:inline-block">
  <div style="max-height:150px;overflow-y:auto; border:1px solid gray">
    <div style="display:inline-block">
      <table border=1><tr>
          <td>I do not</td><td>want this to</td>
          <td>add breaks in the text.</td>
      </tr></table>
      <textarea rows=3 cols=15>Resize me down</textarea>
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block; width:19px; height:1px"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can do it with using this css on the content element: `calc(100% - 15px)`.
// calc(100% - the width we want to give on right hand side of content)
```

Please read below to check how will it work.

Definitely the most easy and less messy way to fix it using the `overflow:scroll.`

But if you do not want to show the scroll when it is not required then you should use the width in with respect to `viewport` (vw) instead of using 100%. As scrollbar comes in the viewport width, if we are aware about the width of scrollbar then we can accomplish our task using the below formula. Here i am setting the content width as viewport width minus the width of the scrollbar(let say 15px).

You need to provide width as: `calc(100% - 15px)`. You can provide width in %, em etc.

The best would be if you override the width of scrollbar like below and then use that width value in your formula to subtract.

```
/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
} 
#content {
  width: calc(100% - 10px).
}
```

**Note: Custom scrollbars are not supported in Firefox or in Edge, prior version 79. And this CSS only works in webkit browsers, so it might not work in IE.**

So you can use 20px of maximim width to subtract becasue scrollbar can never take width more than 20px. Please find below the working code.

```css
.scroll {
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 75%;
}

.zui-table {
      width: calc(100% - 10px);
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif;
}
.zui-table thead th {
    background-color: #DDEFEF;
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    color: #336B6B;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
.zui-table tbody td {
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    color: #333;
    padding: 10px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
  <table class="zui-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Height</th>
        <th>Born</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>DeMarcus Cousins</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>6'11"</td>
        <td>08-13-1990</td>
        <td>$4,917,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Isaiah Thomas</td>
        <td>PG</td>
        <td>5'9"</td>
        <td>02-07-1989</td>
        <td>$473,604</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ben McLemore</td>
        <td>SG</td>
        <td>6'5"</td>
        <td>02-11-1993</td>
        <td>$2,895,960</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Marcus Thornton</td>
        <td>SG</td>
        <td>6'4"</td>
        <td>05-05-1987</td>
        <td>$7,000,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jason Thompson</td>
        <td>PF</td>
        <td>6'11"</td>
        <td>06-21-1986</td>
        <td>$3,001,000</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: from the question *The overall width and height varies.*. You are assuming that the width is equal to screen width

Comment: In that scenario we can set the width of the topmost enclosing parent with the width given by me. So it will not toggle when the scrollbar appears or dissappers. In my opinion we can definitely solve the issue using this approach.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, so `calc(100% - 10px)` then. This is the best answer here, just swap `100vw` to be `100%`. Horizontal scrollbars are harder to solve this way, but fortunately not something OP seems to need.

Comment: @Slbox calc(100% - 10px) will behave the same as 100% because it already consider the scrollbar. The trick with this answer is the use of the vw unit which a dimension not affect by the scrollbar width but (like pixel but pixel is not responsive)

Comment: `100%` will behave the same if the element already takes up `100vw`, otherwise, it's not the same. You note this yourself, _"You are assuming that the width is equal to screen width"_. So use `100%` and that's not an issue. As far as it taking up the entire width, well yeah - that's what `calc()` is being used for in the answer.

Comment: @Slbox try it and show me a working example with `calc(100% - 10px)`

Answer (score 1):

I know that you want achieve this with CSS only, but I am giving a jQuery solution in case someone might find help.

Using jQuery, you can get the scrollbar size and then apply a margin to the container.

Something like this:

```
var checkScrollBars = function(){
    var b = $('body');
    var normalw = 0;
    var scrollw = 0;
    if(b.prop('scrollHeight')>b.height()){
        normalw = window.innerWidth;
        scrollw = normalw - b.width();
        $('#container').css({marginRight:'-'+scrollw+'px'});
    }
}
```

The above code snippet will add a margin if the height of all the content is greater than the container height.

We can also remove the horizontal scrollbar if it isn't needed:

```
body{
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Comment: This is jQuery. You should always state the library/framework you're using

Comment: @GustvandeWal Thanks for your advice. I have changed it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar scenario where I had a grid - heading row and actual data rows below it. The Data rows may be too much and get scrollbar, which will cause the cells in the rows to missalign from the cells in the heading row.

I solved this by using position:absolute on the right column in the rows, which contains a couple of buttons. Don't know if this will be applicable to your case, but it was perfect for mine.

Here is an example:

```js
function toggleMoreRows() {
  document.getElementById('grid-body').classList.toggle('more-rows');
}
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
.grid-heading {
  width: 500px;
  background: #CCC;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.grid-body {
  width: 500px;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.row {
  height: 32px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  position: relative;
}
.row.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.more-rows .row.hidden {
  display: flex;
}
.cell {
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.cell.actions {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<p><button onClick="toggleMoreRows()">Toggle more rows</button></p>

<div class="row grid-heading">
  <div class="cell">First name</div>
  <div class="cell">Last name</div>
  <div class="cell">Age</div>
  <div class="cell actions">Actions</div>
</div>

<div class="grid-body" id="grid-body">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Asdf</div>
    <div class="cell">Asdf</div>
    <div class="cell">12</div>
    <div class="cell actions">
      <button>Edit</button>
      <button>Delete</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Asdf</div>
    <div class="cell">Asdf</div>
    <div class="cell">12</div>
    <div class="cell actions">
      <button>Edit</button>
      <button>Delete</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Asdf</div>
    <div class="cell">Asdf</div>
    <div class="cell">12</div>
    <div class="cell actions">
      <button>Edit</button>
      <button>Delete</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Asdf</div>
    <div class="cell">Asdf</div>
    <div class="cell">12</div>
    <div class="cell actions">
      <button>Edit</button>
      <button>Delete</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row hidden">
    <div class="cell">Asdf</div>
    <div class="cell">Asdf</div>
    <div class="cell">12</div>
    <div class="cell actions">
      <button>Edit</button>
      <button>Delete</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row hidden">
    <div class="cell">Asdf</div>
    <div class="cell">Asdf</div>
    <div class="cell">12</div>
    <div class="cell actions">
      <button>Edit</button>
      <button>Delete</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row hidden">
    <div class="cell">Asdf</div>
    <div class="cell">Asdf</div>
    <div class="cell">12</div>
    <div class="cell actions">
      <button>Edit</button>
      <button>Delete</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row hidden">
    <div class="cell">Asdf</div>
    <div class="cell">Asdf</div>
    <div class="cell">12</div>
    <div class="cell actions">
      <button>Edit</button>
      <button>Delete</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Asdf</div>
    <div class="cell">Asdf</div>
    <div class="cell">12</div>
    <div class="cell actions">
      <button>Edit</button>
      <button>Delete</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is once you hover over the container and the scrollbar appears, then the content width shrinks. So even if you use a nested container whose width is equal to the container minus its scrollbar, the width of nested container will also shrink.

One solution is to increase the size of the contents by the width of the scrollbar on hover.  Here is a solution that doesn't need to use any nested outer containers (`categoryCont` is the scrolling container and each `menuBlock` is one of the items to be scrolled):

```
<div id="categoryCont" style="position:relative;width:200px; overflow:hidden;">
    <div class="menuBlock" style="width:200px">a</div>
    <div class="menuBlock" style="width:200px">b</div>
    <div class="menuBlock" style="width:200px">c</div>
    ...
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    #categoryCont:hover{
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
    #categoryCont:hover .menuBlock{
    /* Increase size of menu block when scrollbar appears */
        width: 218px;    /* Adjust for width of scroll bar. */
    }
</style>
```

One issue with the above is that the width of scrollbar differs slightly in different browsers. One of the following should help:

- By using px

Make the content an absolute value with left indent as an absolute value

```
<div class="menuBlock" style="width:200px">
    a
</div>
```

changes to

```
<div class="menuBlock" style="width:200px">
    <span>a</span>
</div>

<style>
    .menuBlock span{        /* Good cross-browser solution but cannot use % */
        position:absolute;
        left:70px;
    }
</style>
```

- By using %

You need both CSS and jQuery(First step is same)

```
<div class="menuBlock" style="width:200px">
    a
</div>
```

changes to

```
<div class="menuBlock" style="width:200px">
    <span>a</span>
</div>

<style>
    .menuBlock span{        /* Good cross-browser solution but cannot use % */
        position:absolute;  /* This one does not use 'left' */
    }
</style>

<script>
    // Indent left 30% because container width remains same but content width changes
    var leftIndent = (30/100) * $("#categoryCont").width();
    $(".menuBlock span").css({"left":leftIndent});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem recently. So just making body or html to take full viewport width solves the problem.

```css
html {
    width: 100vw;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way i've found for prevent scrollbar overlapping on desktop is

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 640px) {
  body {
    max-width: calc(100dvw - 18px);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really sure what your asking (sorry, I have very little CSS experience), but I think you want to set the width of an HTML `div` element to `100%` with CSS, without having a scroll bar appear. Here is a solution.

```css
#element {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div id="element"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

A scroll bar appears because of the `position`, `margin` and `padding` properties of the `div` element. If you set the `margin-right`, `margin-left`, `padding-right`, and `padding-left` properties to  `0`, and you set the `position` property to `relative`, no scroll bar will appear.

Answer (score -3):

```
* {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

simple way to hide the scrollbar

Comment: This option was included in [@Shounak-Das’ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64927789/3025856).