# Browsers scrollbar is under my fixed div

Tags: css, css-position

i have a fixed header with 100% width.

```
#header {
background: #2e2e2e;
width: 100%;
z-index: 999;
position: fixed;
}
```

browsers scrollbar is under my fixed div. How to fix that?

[image: scrollbar]

Comment: can you provide the live link?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

its because the `overflow-x: hidden;` in base.css line number 9

```
body {
    color: #444444;
    font: 13px/20px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    overflow-x: hidden; // remove this 
}
```

Comment: if i set z-index: -1, than problem is solved. but maybe there is another way?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped! also had to remove   overflow: auto;
 from body. Thank you for your time!

Comment: I don't understand what the solution to this problem was? Seems the OP who started this thread never said what his solution was. I see that z-index:-1 fixed it, however that's not a solution I can use. Was there another way to fix this problem?

Comment: Same problem, CANNOT remove overflow ... solution? We should be able to set the scrollbar z-index to infinite or something

Answer (score 19):

The issue isn't with `overflow-x` on the body tag. It's because of `overflow-x` and`overflow-y` on the **`html`** tag. Once I removed this from the HTML tag, I could put whatever overflow I wanted on my body.

This happens when:

- `overflow-x` is set to either `auto`, `hidden`, `overflow`, or `scroll`
- `overflow-y` is set to either `auto`, `hidden`, `-webkit-paged-x`, or `-webkit-paged-y`

It doesn't have to be an explicit call to `overflow-x` or `overflow-y`, as `overflow` sets both of them.

*I'm on Chrome 67 using Windows 10.*

Answer (score 15):

This can be solved by adding overflow of body

from

```
overflow:auto;
```

to

```
overflow:auto;
overflow:initial;
```

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;

}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.contentWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #888;
}
.Header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  background: #0077cc;
  top: 0;
}
.content {
  height: 140%;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 46px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="contentWrapper">
    <div class="Header">

    </div>
    <div class="content">
      this body scroll bar with overflow set to auto value
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

If your scroll is set on body, if its structured as body > wrapper > header (with fixed position), content so on

below is your solution

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow: initial;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.contentWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #888;
}

.Header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  background: #0077cc;
  top: 0;
}

.content {
  height: 140%;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 46px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="contentWrapper">
    <div class="Header">

    </div>
    <div class="content">
      this body scroll bar with overflow set to initial value
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

*note: this will work only on body but not on div container with scroll. you can also work with z-index to get it to work, but you will be specifying z-index to stack other elements in order to get it right.*

Hope this helps..:)

Comment: You can not add same property with different value twice. The first one will be overridden with the second one and it doesn't solve the problem either for me.

Answer (score 7):

[clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) property can help you.

You need to put your header inside the scrollable content though, but it doesn't matter since it has a fixed position. Then, if you apply `clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);` to the container it will clip out everything outside this rectangle.

```js
function toggle() {
  content.classList.toggle('clip');
}
```

```css
#container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0;
}
#fixed {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 350px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
#content {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}
#content.clip {
  clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    <div id="fixed"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="toggle()">toggle clip-path</button>
```

Comment: It does not work with a custom scroll

Comment: Thank you kindly for this arcane dark magic `clip-path` invocation. I thought I was out of luck when all the other suggestions didn't work. This was exactly what I was missing :)

Answer (score 3):

Had same problem in react app.

Moved `overflow-y: scroll` style from `#root` to `body` selector. It solved issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

The way I solved this problem was setting a scroll bar's width and then setting a 100% width to the navbar minus the scroll bar's width.

Like this:

```css
.main-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
}

.navbar{
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    width: calc(100% - 8px);
    height: 8rem;
    z-index: 5000;
}
```

This is how it looks like

[image: This is how the scrollbar looks like]

Answer (score 2):

A css hack (i finally found a way) for this with not much explanation made quickly - the first floated element is.
I think to understand the principle how it works from the code below.

Update: And there is an issue for mobile browsers see below to assess whether or not youre ok with it.

```
<div style="position: fixed;top: 0;width: 100%;left: 0;z-index: 100000;height: 200px;background: #f00;">

<div id="aaaaa" style="display: block;float:right;color: #000;overflow-y:scroll;min-height:20px;top: -100px;background: #0f0;border: 1px solid #0f0;"></div>
<div id="bbbb" style="display: block;position:relative;color: #000;overflow:hidden;min-height:20px;background: #f0f;border: 1px solid #00f;">sdfasdf sdfas s as as fasd fasd fasdfasd fasd asdf asd fasdf sadf asdf asdf asdf sad fasdf asdf asdf asd fasdf asdf asdf asd fsad sad sfd

        <div style="width: 100%;height: 20px;background: #5ff"></div>

</div>
```

And final code, nearly the same with things you want see visible and working

```
<div style="position: fixed;top: 0;width: 100%;left: 0;z-index: 100000;height: 0px;overflow:visible;background: #f00;">

<div id="aaaaa" style="display: block;float:right;color: #000;overflow-y:scroll;visibility:hidden;min-height:20px;top: -100px;background: #0f0;border: 1px solid #0f0;"></div>
<div id="bbbb" style="display: block;position:relative;color: #000;overflow:hidden;min-height:20px;background: #f0f;border: 1px solid #00f;">sdfasdf sdfas s as as fasd fasd fasdfasd fasd asdf asd fasdf sadf asdf asdf asdf sad fasdf asdf asdf asd fasdf asdf asdf asd fsad sad sfd

        <div style="width: 100%;height: 20px;background: #5ff"></div>

</div>
```

What's important it works with mobile and desktop browsers. Actually for the moment i tested mobile on windows edge when my computer changed into tablet mode and then desktop one. The code works then all the time.
To check is whether or not this works with :before instead of div id="aaaa" to make it more css pure and additional divs intependent.

Update: it doesn't work well with before for Edge browser doesn't change the scrollbar when entering the tablet mode.

If you encounter problems with hidden contents in bbbb element try not to position: absolute/fixed elements in the bbbb container.

I haven't tested it yet for all situations and browsers.

Update: **the issue mentioned** somewhere on the top of this answer - yet on mobile browsers scrollbar is covered because the scrollbar is dynamic - it appears only when your scrolling and you know it is not part of any containers. The scrollbar probably is pretty thin on all browsers, so you should decide what to do with it. Maybe a little 5 pixels margin or so?

Answer (score 2):

Set a `z-index` on the container that is the parent for your header and your content.

Comment: I have tried this and it does not work, although i put it behind everything is still not clickable

Comment: @Kailegh clickable? I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: that with your solution my scroll bar cannot be clicked or dragged down

Comment: @Kailegh without code it's impossible to tell why you are having that issue. I recommend you create a new questions for your issue with example code.

Answer (score 2):

remove `height:100%` in html tag

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and what caused it for me was I had overflow-x: hidden inside my html selector and body selector. So I removed it from the html selector and into the body selector alone.

so:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%; /* <-- was not an issue and remained */
  overflow-x: hidden; /* <-- remove this from html selector */
}
/* to */

body {
  overflow-x: hidden; /* moved it here so then it worked for me */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, my scrollbar was under my fixed header and I solved this after I removed from my html tag `height: 100%;` and I added other proprieties to be sure I have the same result. None of the other solutions helped me. I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue on an angular app,

Irrespective of the overflow attribute I had in other container elements in the hierarchy, Moved overflow: hidden style from html selector to body selector.
It solved issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using 2 ways as below:

1.First caculate the `scrollbarWidth=el.offsetWidth - el.clientWidth`

2.Set fixed `div left=scrollbarWidth`

Comment: Can you explain that further? This does not look like valid CSS to me

Answer (score 0):

put `margin-right: 0px;` on topNavBar works for me