# Make scroll bar take no space / prevent layout shift

Tags: html, css, layout

I am making an application with html and am needing to have a scroll bar. But whenever I add one it shifts everything over to make the necessary room needed for the scroll bar. This screws up the layout of the application.

So I need a way to make the scroll bar simply overlay on top of the page, meaning the page is still there behind it. I already know how to style the scroll bar to make the back transparent, I just need the scroll bar to not take up any space.

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Can you provide your current code, [perhaps with this?](http://jsfiddle.net). My **psychic** powers aren't working well today. Furthermore, if the `scrollbar` isn't taking up any space... how would you scroll...? Your best bet here is to force the scroll bar to ALWAYS show. Alternatively, use padding on your elements so that won't happen.

Comment: If posting code to JSFiddle, then it should also be posted here so that the question is self-contained. Of course, the code should be posted here regardless, but posting only to JSFiddle or the like is not satisfactory.

Comment: i mean the scrollbar is there it's just that the content of the site could be behind it, as if the scrollbar wasn't there, but you can still see it

Comment: @NicholasHazel, if the content doesn't reach to the bottom of the page, the scrollbar will not appear.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's no way to make a scrollbar appear *on top* of your content without using shady hacks, and it's not the best idea anyways since it will affect the usability of your app. If the scroll bar is over the content, it's likely to hide links/text/etc.

Your page ideally should be styled in such a way that it adapts to different browser/page widths without breaking. Especially with just a little scroll bar.

Anyways, here's a workaround that may help:

```
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Adding this style will make sure the scroll bar track is always present, and will also help avoid "jumpy" pages when a scrollbar appears/disappears. Again, the real solution is to use a flexible layout.

As a side note, styling the scrollbar is generally not recommended. It doesn't work cross-browser and will usually be ignored completely.

Comment: ^ Yeah, what he said. +1

Comment: I don't need to worry about cross browser as im using tidesdk which uses webkit only. I guess ill just have to figure out a way to deal with it. Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't even recommend it in webkit, in fact there was a recent update which drastically changed the scrollbar.

Comment: great! I test it and it works as expected.

Comment: Please refer KyleMit answer which work great.

Comment: Horrible answer IMO especially since scrollbars in mobile browsers are overlaid on top of the content BY DEFAULT but oh no using the same for desktop would be a horrible idea. Thanks Mozilla for not letting us "ruin" our applications.

Answer (score 57):

#### Update 2021 - Use `scrollbar-gutter`

The `scrollbar-gutter` CSS property allows authors to reserve space for the scrollbar, preventing unwanted layout changes as the content grows while also avoiding unnecessary visuals when scrolling isn't needed.

```css
body {
  overflow-y: auto;
  scrollbar-gutter: stable;
}
```

#### Example

[image: scrollbar-gutter examples]

#### Demo in Stack Snippets and [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/vdbp6oLe/)

```css
body {
  padding: 16px;
}
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 273px);
    grid-gap: 16px;
}
.card-header {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  white-space: pre-line;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.card-body {
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 120px;
  
}
.scrollbar-stable {
  scrollbar-gutter: stable;
}
```

```html
<h1><code>scrollbar-gutter</code> sample</h1>

<div class="grid">

  <div class="card">
    <pre class="card-header">
overflow: auto;
scrollbar-gutter: auto;
    </pre>
    <div class="card-body">Doggo ipsum length boy noodle horse doing me a frighten doggorino, woofer he made many woofs. Thicc puggorino smol</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card">
    <pre class="card-header">
overflow: auto;
scrollbar-gutter: stable;
    </pre>
    <div class="card-body scrollbar-stable">Doggo ipsum length boy noodle horse doing me a frighten doggorino, woofer he made many woofs. Thicc puggorino smol</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card">
    <pre class="card-header">
overflow: auto;
scrollbar-gutter: auto;
    </pre>
    <div class="card-body">Doggo ipsum length boy noodle horse doing me a frighten doggorino, woofer he made many woofs. Thicc puggorino smol borking doggo with a long snoot for pats shibe long woofer very hand that feed shibe pats, vvv wow such tempt long woofer heckin fluffer. Long water shoob smol corgo sub woofer</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card">
    <pre class="card-header">
overflow: auto;
scrollbar-gutter: stable;
    </pre>
    <div class="card-body scrollbar-stable">Doggo ipsum length boy noodle horse doing me a frighten doggorino, woofer he made many woofs. Thicc puggorino smol borking doggo with a long snoot for pats shibe long woofer very hand that feed shibe pats, vvv wow such tempt long woofer heckin fluffer. Long water shoob smol corgo sub woofer</div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

#### Further Reading

- Docs

  - [scrollbar-gutter | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-gutter)
  - [scrollbar-gutter | CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_scrollbar-gutter)
- Articles

  - [Prevent unwanted Layout Shifts caused by Scrollbars with the scrollbar-gutter](https://www.bram.us/2021/07/23/prevent-unwanted-layout-shifts-caused-by-scrollbars-with-the-scrollbar-gutter-css-property/)
  - [Explainer for the "scrollbar-gutter" CSS property.](https://github.com/felipeerias/scrollbar-gutter-explainer)
  - [scrollbar-gutter | CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scrollbar-gutter/)
- Specs

  - [CSS WG Blog – Minutes Telecon 2021-08-04](https://www.w3.org/blog/CSS/2021/08/05/minutes-telecon-2021-08-04/)
  - [CSS Overflow Module Level 3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-overflow-3/#scrollbar-gutter-property)
- Related

  - [HTML reserve space for scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38266038/1366033)
  - [Prevent scroll-bar from adding-up to the Width of page on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548465/1366033)
  - [Chrome reserves space for scrollbar even if it is hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25942835/1366033)
  - [CSS 100% width but avoid scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541863/1366033)
- **Alternatively**, to have the scrollbar never take up space, see:

  - [Hide scroll bar, but while still being able to scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16670931/1366033)

Comment: Question asks about how to make it not take up space, this makes it always take up space.

Comment: @GlassCannon, question does also ask about how to "prevent layout shift" which this solves, but added a link to some alternate solutions to take up zero space (although this can present challenges for user who rely on scrollbar availability)

Comment: 2023 and this is the preferred solution now

Answer (score 22):

#### Update - `overlay` was webkit-only and is now deprecated.

---

You can use the [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) `overlay` property instead of `scroll`:

```css
html {
    overflow-y: overlay;
}
```

Comment: `overflow: overlay` has been deprecated and should not be used. And is only supported in WebKit based browsers. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Comment: Unfortunately, while it's kinda working it till won't render the content visibly behind the scrollbar's width. It's kinda weird.

Comment: I can't see that this is deprecated. It still works in 2022, and seems like a valid progressive solution for Webkit based browsers.

Comment: please think a 1000 times before `overflow-y: overlay;` property. Happened to use this one project and skewered my animations, also caused necessary problems on mobile.

Answer (score 4):

You can solve this by hiding scrollbar. The solution is in ws3Schools website, https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_hide_scrollbars.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.example {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px dotted black;
  overflow-y: scroll; /* Add the ability to scroll */
}

/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
.example::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
.example {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Hide scrollbar but keep functionality</h2>
<p>Try to scroll inside the div below:</p>

<div class="example">Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not afraid of having something hidden, code below seems to work.

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

@supports (overflow-x: clip) {
  body {
    overflow-x: clip;
  }
}
```

The difference between `clip` and `hidden` is that the `clip` keyword also forbids **all** scrolling, including programmatic scrolling. For browsers don't support `clip`, reset `scrollLeft` to `0` at the scroll event callback of `document.body` if needed.

See also, [browser compatibility of `overflow`](https://caniuse.com/css-overflow).

Answer (score -1):

If you want to hide the scrollbar all the time, can use this code. `*` mean all

```
/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
*{
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
```